# How to speed up slow loading of segue to table view in iphone app

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I have a welcome screen which leads to a table view.
When users tap on a row they are taken via a push segue to a detail view. This loads quickly.
There is also another push segue possible to another table view but this is slow loading.
I think this is because it contains a search bar and data which have to be loaded.
Is there any way I can instantiate this table view when the program loads rather than wait for the segue? The class for the slow loading table view is called `BSGlossaryController`.
I was thinking something along the lines of `myGlossaryController = [[BSGlossaryController alloc]init]` but am not sure.

Comment: Please provide us the code of the segue function, or the next view's viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear or ViewDidAppear method's code. It would be easy to diagnose the problem

Comment: OK Rajan. I will be away from the computer till Wednesday now so will do so then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the BSGlossaryController to instantiate at startup, you should delete the segue to it, instantiate it at startup, and push to it manually. You don't want to use alloc init to instantiate it though, that will create a different one than the one in your storyboard. You want to use the UIStoryboard method instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier: to instantiate it (and make sure you give it an identifier in IB). When it comes time to push to it, you'll want to hook your button (or whatever you're using to trigger the push) to a method that uses pushViewController:animated: to do the push.

If you do this at startup (in the app delegate), then you'll have to assign the newly created BSGlossaryController to a property, and access that in which ever controller you're going to push from. If you can wait to instantiate it until that controller (the one you're pushing from) is on screen, then you can create it in that controller's viewDidLoad method.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you don't want to load one giant chunk of data at a time. If the chunk is large enough to significantly slow down your view loading, it's a good bet that you need to rethink your approach. Memory issues aside, loading large amounts of data at one time will block the UI of your app as it's loading. This will leave the app unresponsive and the user will wonder what is going on.

You can handle loading large data sets in a few different ways -- presented in order of preference:

- Use an [`NSFetchedResultsController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to load your data. This will automatically take care of caching and chunking the data so responsiveness and performance are maintained.
- Break your data into smaller subsets. The screen can only display so much data at a time, so it's pointless to load data into memory that isn't currently being presented. Bring in new data as the view requires it.
- First present the view (without data), display an activity indicator with a message informing the user that the data load is happening, then bring in the data asynchronously on a background thread. This approach will at least not leave the user wondering what is going on.

Once you post some code and I have a better idea about what you are trying to do and why, I can give more specific answers.

Comment: Thank you for that. NSFetchedResultsController was a little complicated for me to master in a hurry so I cleaned up the code so that there was less loading to do.

Comment: Sorry about that. I thought about it and then I thought I would try and instantiate the view at startup.

Comment: That is not a good approach. You aren't addressing the issue, but rather just pushing it off onto another object. In addition, any type of heavy lifting is a really, really bad idea to put in the app delegate, especially if it is synchronous. Springboard (the daemon that is responsible for launching apps) _will_ terminate your app if it doesn't finish loading in a certain amount of time.

Comment: Yes, upon reflection, you were right all along. The approach I took in the end was to simplify the code so it loaded more quickly, sacrificing some of the complexity. It would have taken me longer than I have to learn the NSFetchedResultsController. Thank you for your advice which I shall refer to again when the need arises.